# jquery DatePicker - numeric month dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, dom, datepicker

I have an HTML input element for my datepicker... pretty normal

```
<input type="text" id="from_date">
```

And a pretty normal setup for allowing the Month / Year changes

```
$('#from_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

But the Month dropdown shows names like "Jan" instead of "1" or "01"

How can I change the dropdown values to be the numerical representation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check datepicker options here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
$('#from_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    monthNames: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"],
    monthNamesShort: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
});
```

This might be a solution.

Comment: Thank you!! I would upvote this 5x if possible.  Any idea when this feature was added?  All of my google-searches turned up as "this is not possible" and even one link from the date-picker project that said it would not be implemented.

Comment: No idea, too bad that there are no dates of revision in the documentation.